# Indefinite integral problem. I don't see the trick!

Tags: indefinite-integrals

So I have this indefinite integral:

$$ \int \frac{x}{1+x^4} \, dx$$

My initial hunch is to make $u = 1 + x^4$ but the derivative of that is $4x^3$ but that there is an x in the numerator of the integrand. So I don't see how I can do a u substitution since $x^3 \ne x$. What can I do???!!

Comment: try $u=x^2$....

Comment: No. It's not so difficult. Try substituting $x^2=u$ (suggested by the $x$ in the numerator).

Comment: The derivative of $\frac{1}{2}\arctan(x^2)$ seems to be... $\frac{x}{1+x^4}$.

Answer (score 3):

Use a substitution $y=x^2.$ Then:
$$\int \frac{x}{1+x^4}\, dx=\frac 12\int\frac1{1+y^2}\, dy=\frac{\arctan y}2+c=\frac{\arctan x^2}2+c$$

Answer (score 2):

$$ \int \frac{x}{1+x^4} \, dx= \frac12\int \frac{2x}{1+(x^2)^2} \, dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $u=x^2$ then use the integral of $arctan(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int \frac{x}{1+x^4} \, dx $$

Substitute u = $x^2$ -> $dx = \frac{1}{2x} \, du $

$$= \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{u^2 + 1} \, du $$

The standard integral $ \int \frac{1}{u^2+1} \, du = arctan(u) $

$$ \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{u^2 + 1} \, du = \frac{arctan(u)}{2} $$

undo substitution $ u = x{^2} $

$$ = \frac{arctan(x{^2})}{2} + C $$